# Device Manager won't open from search in Win-Server 2019

Tags: windows

If I type device manager in search bar in Windows Server 2019, I get the following error -

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.
```

It opens normally from Run Command. What should I do?

Comment: What is the path that is trying to be opened?

Comment: I do not know about that.

Comment: When you find something in search there's an option to view the file.

Comment: Nope, at least not on windows Server 2019.

Comment: Does anything come up when you type in `devmgmt.msc`?

Comment: Only the above mentioned error comes up.